# How to add filter in ag-grid Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, mean, ag-grid-angular

I want to implement a filter with a text box(like a search). I am trying to implement it as follows,

```
 this.columnDefs = [
  {
    field: 'athlete',
    filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
  }]
```

The type of the field is string.

But this giving me something like this,

[image: img1]

but I want like below where I can type and search.

[image: Img2]

Can any one pls suggest me help.Thanks.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `agSetColumnFilter` filter which allows you to select from a list of values to filter by. You need to use the `agTextColumnFilter` filter (see [Here](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/filtering/#provided-filters)).

Change your code to:

```
  this.columnDefs = [
  {
    field: 'athlete',
    floatingFilter: true
    filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
  }]
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-cjcioy?file=src/app/app.component.ts).